# Populate data on same window

Tags: html, jsp

[image]

Hi,  my requirement is to populate the data on same window where i have provide the employee id , Employee Id button and input field is present on left corner the of window and i want to populate the data on right corner of window  as shown on figure right now i m population data on different window please help me out .

Here is my **JS**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<jsp:include page="Header.jsp" />
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link href="../css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <table width="1255" height="952" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="357" height="251" bgcolor="#CC6600">
                <table width="285" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#FF9900">




                    <c:if test="${requestScope.x}">
                        <div id="div3">
                            <form:form commandName="departmentForm"
                                action="/EmployeeWebAppUI/DepartmentController/findbydepartmentid">
                                <span>Find By ID </span>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <form:input path="departmentId" />
                                <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="search" />

                            </form:form>

                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </c:if>

                    <c:if test="${requestScope.y}">
                        <div id="div1">
                            <form:form commandName="departmentForm"
                                action="/EmployeeWebAppUI/DepartmentController/findbydepartmentname">
                                <span>Find BY Name</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;<form:input
                                    path="departmentName" />
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search" />
                            </form:form>

                        </div>
                    </c:if>

                    <c:if test="${requestScope.w}">
                        <div id="div2">
                            <form:form commandName="projectForm"
                                action="/EmployeeWebAppUI/ProjectController/getprojectsbyId">
                                <span>Employee Number: </span>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <form:input path="employeeNumber" />
                                <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="search" />

                            </form:form>

                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </c:if>




                    <c:if test="${requestScope.A}">
                        <div id="div2">
                            <form:form commandName="employeeForm"
                                action="/EmployeeWebAppUI/EmployeeGetController/findbyid"
                                method="get">
                                <span>Employee Id:</span>

                                <form:input path="employeeNumber" />

                                <input type="submit" name="Search" value="Search" />

                            </form:form>
                        </div>
                    </c:if>

                    <c:if test="${requestScope.B}">
                        <div id="div1">
                            <form:form commandName="employeeForm"
                                action="/EmployeeWebAppUI/EmployeeGetController/findbyname"
                                method="post">

                                <span>Employee Name:</span>

                                <form:input path="firstName" />

                                <input type="submit" name="Search" value="Search" />

                            </form:form>
                        </div>
                    </c:if>


                    <c:if test="${requestScope.C}">
                        <div id="div1">
                            <form:form commandName="employeeForm"
                                action="/EmployeeWebAppUI/EmployeeGetController/findByDepatmentId"
                                method="post">

                                <span>Department ID:</span>

                                <form:input path="departmentId" />

                                <input type="submit" name="Search" value="Search" />

                            </form:form>
                        </div>
                    </c:if>

                </table>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td width="888" rowspan="2">
        <tr>
            <td height="693" bgcolor="#CC6600"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting complete page get only data from Server and then render data on page using JavaScript.

This is typically possible if you post page **asynchronously** ( or using Ajax). The way you do is :

- Call action by passing input parameters to the server using Ajax.
- Get response in JSON form from server
- Parse JSON data and then populate page using DOM manipulation.

You can use any JS library like **jQuery** to simplify your Ajax call as well as doing DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jquery

on click of tab or lable do AJAX request .

It will call your servlet and write the data into ajax response there.

on client side onsuccess do the required stuff .

```
function changeCOntent(type){
    $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'servletpath?type=passtype',
          success:function(data){

             $('#contentDiv').innerHTML = data;

          }
        });
}
```

Comment: thanx for replying but i m not using jquery i m using spring on this project do u know other way except this